# Html.fromHtml hide text between "<" and ">"

Tags: android

This is sorce code

```java
String testText = "<(￣3￣)> &#128517;Σ( ° △ °|||)︴test text&#128544;♪(＾∀＾●)ﾉ";
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(testText));
```

I got these on phone screen `Σ( ° △ °|||)︴test text♪(＾∀＾●)ﾉ`.

`<(￣3￣)>` is lost.

Comment: What exactly is the question? Are you expecting different outcome? Have you looked at the documentation for Html.fromHtml for the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Html.fromHtml** identifies **< >** as tags so you need to escape them manually if you need to display them

```
String testText = "&lt;(￣3￣)&gt; &#128517;Σ( ° △ °|||)︴test text&#128544;♪(＾∀＾●)ﾉ";
t.setText(Html.fromHtml(testText));
```

Note : `&lt;` is < symbol and `&gt;` is > symbol